# PHPSESSID via get

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm trying to do some session fixation in my local website! :)
I've read that if I send this request:

*http://dev5.mysite.local/?PHPSESSID=abc123*

`$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` will be `abc123`!

Why it is null? (I have after deleted session's cookies)

I don't understand how a variable in get should be saved as cookie `superglobals`!

Comment: Where did you read that? Are you sure you're not thinking of passing the session ID via GET (http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php), which stores the session ID in `SID` (or `session_id()`) ?

Comment: i read the page and i tried to pass SID. 
Why i can pass SID only if cookies are disabled?
If cookie are enabled, SID is empty and $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] is filled.
It seems that SID passed via get work only if cookies are disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: PHP will only accept a session ID if its syntax is valid in terms of the current session ID configuration (i.e. [*session.hash_function*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function) and [*session.hash_bits_per_character*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-bits-per-character)).

But if your providing a valid session ID within the URL while the configuration of accepting session IDs allows both via URL and cookie (i.e. [*session.use_trans_sid*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) and [*session.use_cookies*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies) are enabled and [*session.use_only_cookies*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies) is disabled), then PHP’s default session handler will use that session ID but it won’t set a session ID cookie.

So, no, requesting *http://dev5.mysite.local/?PHPSESSID=abc123* will not set a corresponding cookie.

Comment: my parameters are:
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.use_cookies = 0
session.use_only_cookies = off

So i think that the problem is session.use_trans_sid = 0, right?
How many parameters there are in php.ini?!??! is impossible to know all! :)

Comment: @D. Milito: So all three (*session.use\_trans\_sid*, *session.use\_cookies*, *session.use\_only\_cookies*) are disabled? Well, then session shouldn’t work at all.

Comment: sorry, session.use_cookies = On.....i try to set session.use_trans_sid = 1, but dev5.mysite.local/?PHPSESSID=abc123 doesn't work! $_COOKIES['PHPSESSID'] = null

Comment: @D. Milito: You need to provide a syntactically valid session ID; otherwise it’s getting rejected.

Comment: nothing, i try with an existing PHPSESSID (like is1bgnvvllb84h53pq5ubg94u6), but dev5.mysite.local/?PHPSESSID=is1bgnvvllb84h53pq5ubg94u6 doesn't work! this request is syntactically valid?

Comment: @D. Milito: Ok, I have to admit that I was wrong with saying that a session ID cookie will be set.

Comment: @Gumbo: :) ok, thanks for your answers!
but do you know how to set the PHPSESSID in $_cookie via get and what are the right php parameters? just to try a working example! :)

Comment: As of PHP 5.3, session.use_trans_sid = 1, session.use_cookies = 0 session.use_only_cookies = 0 needs to be set for PHPSESSID via GET to work.  I tried it with session.use_cookies = 1, with the cookies cleared and the PHPSESSID in the GET parameters, but it still wouldn't accept the session id until I disabled, session.use_cookies.